# pygame both audial and visual sine wave

Tags: python, audio, pygame, trigonometry

Here is a function from my program, it called when a key is pressed. What is supposed to happen is the key is pressed and a corresponding note is played, and a sine wave appears on the screen also. The sound plays fine, so I won't post any more code for the sound, but it is just the visual side of things that don't work, why won't this wave show?

```
WINDOWWIDTH = 640 # width of the program's window, in pixels
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480 # height in pixels
WIN_CENTERX = int(WINDOWWIDTH / 2) # the midpoint for the width of the window
WIN_CENTERY = int(WINDOWHEIGHT / 2) # the midpoint for the height of the window
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
fontObj = pygame.font.SysFont('freesansbold.ttf', 16)
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

# set up a bunch of constants
BLUE       = (  0,   0, 255)
WHITE      = (255, 255, 255)
DARKRED    = (128,   0,   0)
DARKBLUE   = (  0,   0, 128)
RED        = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN      = (  0, 255,   0)
DARKGREEN  = (  0, 128,   0)
YELLOW     = (255, 255,   0)
DARKYELLOW = (128, 128,   0)
BLACK      = (  0,   0,   0)

BGCOLOR = WHITE

FPS = 160 # frames per second to run at

pause = False


# making text Surface and Rect objects for various labels
sinLabelSurf = fontObj.render('sine', True, RED, BGCOLOR)
squareLabelSurf = fontObj.render('square', True, BLUE, BGCOLOR)

sinLabelRect = sinLabelSurf.get_rect()
squareLabelRect = squareLabelSurf.get_rect()

def MakeSineWave(freq=1000):
    #### visual part ####
    xPos = 0
    step = 0
    AMPLITUDE = 80 # how many pixels tall the waves with rise/fall.
    posRecord = {'sin': [], 'line': []}

    yPos = -1 * math.sin(step) * AMPLITUDE
    posRecord['sin'].append((int(xPos), int(yPos) + WIN_CENTERY))

    # draw the sine ball and label
    pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, DARKRED, (int(xPos), int(yPos) + WIN_CENTERY), 10)
    sinLabelRect.center = (int(xPos), int(yPos) + WIN_CENTERY + 20)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(sinLabelSurf, sinLabelRect)

    # draw the waves from the previously recorded ball positions
    for x, y in posRecord['sin']:
        pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, DARKRED, (x, y), 4)

    # draw the border
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, (0, 0, WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 1)

    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

    if not pause:
        xPos += 0.5
        if xPos > WINDOWWIDTH:
            xPos = 0
            posRecord = {'sin': []}
            step = 0
        else:
            step += 0.008

    #### audial part ####
    return MakeSound(SineWave(freq))
```

Comment: Does `MakeSound` return straight away or does it wait until the sound has completed playing? Or, does your display code work if you don't call `MakeSound` at all? First you have be sure about where your bug is and isn't.

Comment: makesound returns straight away, or it certainly seems to anyway. I commented out the return and the display still doesn't show

Comment: I must be missing something, as I don't see any specific code that would actually draw a sine curve. You've got the `posRecord` data, but that only appears to contain one element.

Comment: I am trying to implement this code into my pre-made audial code:

http://inventwithpython.com/trig_waves.py

Comment: That code seems considerably different to what you have posted in the question. Are you saying that you posted code in the question that is not the code you're actually using?

Comment: I have taken the code from that link and included what I thought originally to be necessary into my own code for the sound, is there something in that code that is not in mine? Original code has been edited to show the global variables and such that I also added outside of this function

Comment: Oh I see, you didn't write the `trig_waves.py` code, you're starting with that. Yes, there is quite a lot in the original code that is not in yours. The structure is completely different too; for example your `posRecord` is a local variable, while the original had it as a global variable. I would suggest starting with *working* code and modifying it to add your additional audio function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run `MakeSineWave` only once - when button is pressed - but code which draws wave have to be run all the time in all loop. It draws longer wave in every loop.

It seems you ask in another question how to draw all wave and move only red ball - and answer need differen changes in `MakeSineWave` then changes for this question.

---

**EDIT:** It is working code - but there is a mess - it needs less code directly in mainloop but more code in some new functions.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import math
import numpy

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# functions
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

def SineWave(freq=1000, volume=16000, length=1):

    num_steps = length * SAMPLE_RATE
    s = []

    for n in range(num_steps):
        value = int(math.sin(n * freq * (6.28318/SAMPLE_RATE) * length) * volume)
        s.append( [value, value] )

    return numpy.array(s)

#-------------------

def SquareWave(freq=1000, volume=100000, length=1):

    num_steps = length * SAMPLE_RATE
    s = []

    length_of_plateau = int( SAMPLE_RATE / (2*freq) )

    print num_steps, length_of_plateau

    counter = 0
    state = 1

    for n in range(num_steps):

        value = state * volume

        s.append( [value, value] )

        counter += 1

        if counter == length_of_plateau:
            counter = 0
            state *= -1

    return numpy.array(s)

#-------------------

def MakeSound(arr):
    return pygame.sndarray.make_sound(arr)

#-------------------

def MakeSquareWave(freq=1000):
    return MakeSound(SquareWave(freq))

#-------------------

def MakeSineWave(freq=1000):
    return MakeSound(SineWave(freq))

#-------------------

def DrawSineWave():

    # sine wave

    yPos = -1 * math.sin(step) * AMPLITUDE
    posRecord['sin'].append((int(xPos), int(yPos) + WIN_CENTERY))
    if showSine:
        # draw the sine ball and label
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (int(xPos), int(yPos) + WIN_CENTERY), 10)
        sinLabelRect.center = (int(xPos), int(yPos) + WIN_CENTERY + 20)
        screen.blit(sinLabelSurf, sinLabelRect)

    # draw the waves from the previously recorded ball positions
    if showSine:
        for x, y in posRecord['sin']:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, DARKRED, (x, y), 4)


#-------------------

def DrawSquareWave():

    # square wave

    posRecord['square'].append((int(xPos), int(yPosSquare) + WIN_CENTERY))
    if showSquare:
        # draw the square ball and label
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, GREEN, (int(xPos), int(yPosSquare) + WIN_CENTERY), 10)
        squareLabelRect.center = (int(xPos), int(yPosSquare) + WIN_CENTERY + 20)
        screen.blit(squareLabelSurf, squareLabelRect)

    # draw the waves from the previously recorded ball positions
    if showSquare:
        for x, y in posRecord['square']:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, (x, y), 4)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# constants - (uppercase name)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

# set up a bunch of constants
WHITE      = (255, 255, 255)
DARKRED    = (128,   0,   0)
RED        = (255,   0,   0)
BLACK      = (  0,   0,   0)
GREEN      = (  0, 255,   0)
BLUE       = (  0,   0, 255)

BGCOLOR = WHITE

WINDOWWIDTH = 1200 # width of the program's window, in pixels
WINDOWHEIGHT = 720 # height in pixels

WIN_CENTERX = int(WINDOWWIDTH / 2) # the midpoint for the width of the window
WIN_CENTERY = int(WINDOWHEIGHT / 2) # the midpoint for the height of the window

FPS = 160 # frames per second to run at

AMPLITUDE = 80 # how many pixels tall the waves with rise/fall.

#-------------------

SAMPLE_RATE = 22050 ## This many array entries == 1 second of sound.

SINE_WAVE_TYPE = 'Sine'
SQUARE_WAVE_TYPE = 'Square'

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# main program
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

#-------------------
# variables (which don't depend on pygame)
#-------------------

sound_types = {SINE_WAVE_TYPE:SQUARE_WAVE_TYPE, SQUARE_WAVE_TYPE:SINE_WAVE_TYPE}

current_type = SINE_WAVE_TYPE
current_played = { 'z': None, 'c': None }
current_drawn = None

#-------------------

# variables that track visibility modes
showSine = True
showSquare = True

xPos = 0
step = 0 # the current input f

posRecord = {'sin': [], 'square': []} # keeps track of the ball positions for drawing the waves

yPosSquare = AMPLITUDE # starting position

#-------------------
# start program
#-------------------

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
pygame.display.set_caption('Nibbles!')

# making text Surface and Rect objects for various labels

pygame.display.set_caption('Trig Waves')
fontObj = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 16)

### HERE 
squareLabelSurf = fontObj.render('square', True, BLUE, BGCOLOR)
squareLabelRect = squareLabelSurf.get_rect()

sinLabelSurf = fontObj.render('sine', True, RED, BGCOLOR)
sinLabelRect = sinLabelSurf.get_rect()

#-------------------
# mainloop
#-------------------

fps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()

_running = True

while _running:

    #-------------------
    # events
    #-------------------

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            _running = False

        # some keys don't depend on `current_type`

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                _running = False

            if event.key == K_RETURN:
                current_type = sound_types[current_type]  #Toggle
                print 'new type:', current_type

        # some keys depend on `current_type`

        if current_type == SINE_WAVE_TYPE:

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:

                #lower notes DOWN

                if event.key == K_z:
                    print current_type, 130.81
                    current_played['z'] = MakeSineWave(130.81)
                    current_played['z'].play()
                    current_drawn = DrawSineWave

                elif event.key == K_c:
                    print current_type, 180.81
                    current_played['c'] = MakeSineWave(180.81)
                    current_played['c'].play()
                    current_drawn = DrawSineWave

            elif event.type == KEYUP:

                #lower notes UP

                if event.key == K_z:
                    current_played['z'].fadeout(350)
                    current_drawn = None

                    #sine - reset data
                    xPos = 0
                    posRecord['sin'] = []
                    step = 0

                elif event.key == K_c:
                    current_played['c'].fadeout(350)
                    current_drawn = None

                    #sine - reset data
                    xPos = 0
                    posRecord['sin'] = []
                    step = 0

        elif current_type == SQUARE_WAVE_TYPE:

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:

                #lower notes DOWN

                if event.key == K_z:
                    print current_type, 130.81
                    current_played['z'] = MakeSquareWave(130.81)
                    current_played['z'].play()
                    current_drawn = DrawSquareWave

                elif event.key == K_c:
                    print current_type, 180.81
                    current_played['c'] = MakeSquareWave(180.81)
                    current_played['c'].play()
                    current_drawn = DrawSquareWave

            elif event.type == KEYUP:

                #lower notes UP

                if event.key == K_z:
                    current_played['z'].fadeout(350)
                    current_drawn = None

                    # square - reset data
                    xPos = 0
                    yPosSquare = AMPLITUDE
                    posRecord['square'] = []
                    step = 0

                elif event.key == K_c:
                    current_played['c'].fadeout(350)
                    current_drawn = None

                    # square - reset data
                    xPos = 0
                    yPosSquare = AMPLITUDE
                    posRecord['square'] = []
                    step = 0

    #-------------------
    # draws
    #-------------------

    # fill the screen to draw from a blank state
    screen.fill(BGCOLOR)

    if current_drawn:
        current_drawn()

    pygame.display.update()

    #-------------------
    # moves
    #-------------------

    if current_drawn:
        xPos += 1.0 #0.5

        if xPos > WINDOWWIDTH:
            #sine ### HERE
            xPos = 0
            posRecord['sin'] = []
            step = 0

            # square ### HERE
            yPosSquare = AMPLITUDE
            posRecord['square'] = []
        else:
            #sine ### HERE
            step += 0.008
            #step %= 2 * math.pi

            # square ### HERE
            # jump top and bottom every 100 pixels
            if xPos % 100 == 0:
                yPosSquare *= -1
                # add vertical line
                for x in range(-AMPLITUDE, AMPLITUDE):
                    posRecord['square'].append((int(xPos), int(x) + WIN_CENTERY))

    #-------------------
    # FPS
    #-------------------

    fps_clock.tick(FPS)

#-------------------
# end program
#-------------------

pygame.quit()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you so much, once again you prove to be a great help :)

Comment: There's an underlying notion here and that is the fact that the Pygame documentation has insufficient documentation  with regard to generated sounds. The audio tutorials assume you will import .WAV sound effects, and do not cater to the concept of programmatically generating tones/sounds. I say that because I've looked at the Pygame docs and examples for just this type of example, and with some Googling I found this great example here. Thank you @furas.